# disabling button on specific condition on r

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, user-interface

I am using below code for pagination.

```
  <ul className="pagination">
          <li className="page-item">
            <button  className="page-link btn btn-success btn-block"  onClick={prev} >Previous</button>
          </li>
          <li className="page-item">
            <button className="page-link btn btn-success btn-block " onClick={next}>Next</button>
          </li>
        </ul>


 const next = () => {
    if (page <= lastPage) {
      setPage(page + 1);
    }
  }
  const prev = () => {
    if (page > 1) {
      setPage(page - 1);
    }
  }
```

my requirement is when data of `first page` is getting displayed then `prev` button should be disabled. when data of `lastpage` is getting displayed then `next`button should be disabled.

I mean `if(page==1)` disable`prev` and  `if(page==lastPage)`disable  `next` .how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally disable a button using an expression on the `disabled` property of the button. For example, for the Previous Button, you can do this,

```
<button disabled={page == 1} className="page-link btn btn-success btn-block"  onClick={prev} >Previous</button>
```

You can follow the same thing for the Next button too. Just change the expression to `page == lastPage`

But make sure that the `page` property is a state of the component so that React automatically refreshes the component when it changes. Regarding your use of `setPage` I suppose it's already the case

Comment: Thank you Jahir , your answer worked. only correction instead of disable, it is disabled in react.

Comment: My bad. I've updated the answer with the correct name. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement other methods like disabling the button on page load or something like that, but if you want to keep it simple just add alerts.

NOTE: You had a bug in the first conditional because if you have 50 pages and the actual page is 50, the condition `(page <= lastpage)` will be true and you will send the user to the page 51 that doesn't exist.

```js
const next = () => {
  if (page < lastPage) {
    setPage(page + 1);
  } else {
    alert("This is the last page");
  }
}
const prev = () => {
  if (page > 1) {
    setPage(page - 1);
  } else {
    alert("This is the first page");
  }
}
```

```html
<ul className="pagination">
  <li className="page-item">
    <button className="page-link btn btn-success btn-block" onClick={prev}>Previous</button>
  </li>
  <li className="page-item">
    <button className="page-link btn btn-success btn-block " onClick={next}>Next</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```